# xampp redirects

Tags: xampp, url-rewriting

Does anyone has an example how to do a rule in .httpaccess in xampp?

I'm trying to redirect from localhost/test/company.php?name=Abc to localhost/test/company/Abc and I cant seem to find the solution. I followed some examples that I found on the web but none seems to work. I'm putting the .htacces file in the same folder where I have the company.php file. And I have the urlrewrite turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `.htaccess` file in your application root.

The `.htaccess` file should have something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^company/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ /company.php?name=$1 [L,NC]
```

[Turn on mod_rewrite](http://thephpcode.blogspot.com/2009/07/enabling-extensionsdll-in-php-of-xampp.html) and restart apache.

Then it should work.